# how to change img class when any checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, css, class, checkbox

In one php file I have this image which has class name "notselected".

I have several checkboxes in other php file.

Content of the second php file is loaded with ajax into a div in first php file.

I want to change image class to "selected" if any checkboxes in loaded content is clicked/selected.

My code in first php file:

```
<img id="image" src="empty.png" class="notselected" />

    .notselected {
        width: 340px;         
        height: 91px;   
        background: url(image.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;    
        cursor:not-allowed;
}

.selected {
        width: 340px;         
        height: 91px;   
        background: url(image.png) 0px -91px no-repeat;    
        cursor:pointer;
}
```

My code in second php file:

```
 foreach ($examples as $example)
{
echo '<input id="select" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="example" value="example" />';
}
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Where should this be happening, client-side (***show the HTML***) or server-side?

Comment: client-side, its just the page layout for now

Comment: Right. If it's client-side why are we looking at PHP, and *not* HTML (which is what the client sees)?

Comment: well... we do :) i saved you lots of php code and pasted just the "echo". Of course it should be just html taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually this works:

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
{
    var rejestruj=0;    

    $(".checkbox").each(function(i, obj) {
        $(obj).change(function()
        {
            if ( $(obj).attr('checked') == true)
            {
                rejestruj++;
                $("#image").addClass("selected");
            }
            else
            {
                rejestruj--;
                if (!rejestruj) $("#image").removeClass("selected");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

thx all!

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with jquery easily just add click event to check box and toggle the `select` class

```
   $(".checkbox").change(function () {
      $("#image").toggleClass("selected");
    });
```

here a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xTxb4/)

Comment: +1 But to add, it might be better to use "change" instead of click.

Comment: this will work only for the first checkbox element... I have more of them (foreach) and any of them should trigger the img class change http://jsfiddle.net/54Dzr/

Comment: this ".checkbox" now will switch between notselected and selected with every click, which is not what i want to achieve. I need it to be "selected" if any is selected, and "notselected" if none of them is selected